# How to print scrollable div content using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, printing

I have tried multiple different avenues on trying to get this to work and when rendering the print media query using dev tools I get a scrollable div but when printing I just get 1 page. I've attached my css below.

```
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  #print,
  #print * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #print {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general, and I'm not going to try to answer you, however I will tell you how to try to solve it yourself.

Using Chrome's dev tools, it is possible to see how the page would look like when printed. Press F12 to open dev tools, then under `Rendering` find the `Emulate CSS media type` and select `print` - then you can play around with styles on the `Elements` page and see how that would translate to a printed version.

Comment: I am doing that, like I said in my question I am getting a scrollable div when doing that but when I try to print I am only getting 1 page and not all of the content

Comment: Try to create a stackblitz that shows the problem